# How can two variables to equal the screen size and width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-size

Hello I am trying to move images around depending on the screen size fore example iPhone 3.5" or 4". To do this I am pulling the screen size and then setting the center of the image to the screen width and height minus a certain amount. The only problem is the screen size is not changing like it should be. It is saying that the iPhone 3.5" and 4" have the same dimensions which they obviously do not. How do I fix this?

This is the current code I am using to pull the dimensions:

```
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
Height = screenSize.width;
Width = screenSize.height;
```

Comment: use viewdidapper mathod

Comment: viewdidappear didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define kSizeScreenWidth         320
#define kSizeScreenHeight        [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height //480

#define kDeviceVersionAvailable  3.2
#define kDeviceVersion           [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]
#define kDeviceScreenWidth       kDeviceVersion < kDeviceVersionAvailable ? kSizeScreenWidth : [[[UIScreen mainScreen] currentMode] size].width
#define kDeviceScreenHeight      kDeviceVersion < kDeviceVersionAvailable ? kSizeScreenHeight : [[[UIScreen mainScreen] currentMode] size].height
```

If your app device version >= 3.2, then just try this:

```
#define kDeviceScreenWidth  [[[UIScreen mainScreen] currentMode] size].width
#define kDeviceScreenHeight [[[UIScreen mainScreen] currentMode] size].height
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting this code? I seem to remember that in viewDidLoad the view controller's content view is a default size, and then you get an update layout call with the new size.

Try putting your logic in viewWillLayoutSubviews instead.

Comment: It still is giving me wrong dimensions in viewWllLayouSubviews